# Add closing balance columns as per transaction (income-expenses)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a table like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcaMc.png)

I want to add a closing balance column which will be

=sum(income)-sum(expenses) as per date
(like if date is 11 july 2016 than sum (income till 11 july 2016) - sum (expenses till 11 july 2016)

My query is here

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

SELECT TOP 1000 [uniqe_id]
  ,[entry_type]
  ,[date]
  ,[category]
  ,[description]
  ,[income]
  ,[expenses]
   ??????
 FROM [App_data].[dbo].[RC02]
 order by date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use windowed [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) (`SQL Server 2012+`):

```
SELECT *,
  [closing_balance] = SUM(ISNULL(income, 0) - ISNULL(expense,0)) OVER (ORDER BY [date])
FROM RC02
ORDER BY date;
```

If you need to calculate it per `user/...` use `PARTITION BY ...`.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.